# How to stop the alarm from another activity

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am setting the alarm from the `MainActivity` and stopping it from another activity (`FakeRinger`Activity).
This is the `MainActivity` code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String LOG_TAG = "MainActivity";

    ImageView imageView;
    EditText number, name;
    Button setTimeButton;
    FloatingActionButton fab;
    Calendar calendar;
    long selectedTimeInMillis;
    TimePickerDialog timePicker;
    String enteredName, enteredNumber;
    Intent intent;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    private static final int SELECT_IMAGE = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.settings, false);

        imageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        setTimeButton = findViewById(R.id.set_time);
        fab = findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);

        number = findViewById(R.id.number);
        name = findViewById(R.id.name);

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, SELECT_IMAGE);
            }
        });

        setTimeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                timePicker = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
                        selectedTimeInMillis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

                        if (hourOfDay > 12) {
                            hourOfDay = hourOfDay - 12;
                        }

                        if (minute < 10) {
                            String minuteStr = "0" + String.valueOf(minute);
                            minute = Integer.parseInt(minuteStr);
                            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "minute is :" + minute);
                        }

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, hourOfDay + ":" + minute, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Selected time in millis:" + selectedTimeInMillis);
                    }
                }, hour, minute, false);
                timePicker.show();
            }
        });

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                enteredName = name.getText().toString().trim();
                enteredNumber = number.getText().toString().trim();
                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReciever.class);
                intent.putExtra("FAKE_NAME", enteredName);
                intent.putExtra("FAKE_NUMBER", enteredNumber);
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                if (alarmManager != null) {
                    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, selectedTimeInMillis, pendingIntent);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Your call has been placed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error: something wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.settings:
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;

            case R.id.quick_call:
                quickCall();
                return true;

                default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                InputStream imageStream = null;
                if (imageUri != null) {
                    imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                }
                Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked any Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void quickCall(){
        enteredName = name.getText().toString().trim();
        enteredNumber = number.getText().toString().trim();

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        long millis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

        intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReciever.class);
        intent.putExtra("FAKE_NAME", enteredName);
        intent.putExtra("FAKE_NUMBER", enteredNumber);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        if (alarmManager != null) {
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, millis+10000, pendingIntent);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Your call has been placed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error: something wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the  `AlarmReceiver` class:

```
public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String getFakeName = intent.getStringExtra("FAKE_NAME");
        String getFakeNumber = intent.getStringExtra("FAKE_NUMBER");

        Intent fakeRinger = new Intent();
        fakeRinger.setClassName("com.example.mani.fakecall", "com.example.mani.fakecall.FakeRinger");
        fakeRinger.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        fakeRinger.putExtra("USER_FAKE_NAME", getFakeName);
        fakeRinger.putExtra("USER_FAKE_NUMBER", getFakeNumber);
        context.startActivity(fakeRinger);
    }
}
```

And this is the `FakeRinger` activity from where I want to stop the alarm.

```
public class FakeRinger extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView displayName, displayNumber, displayCarrier;
    ImageButton alarmOffButton;
    String carrierName;
    ImageView displayImage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fake_ringer);

        displayName = findViewById(R.id.display_name);
        displayNumber = findViewById(R.id.display_number);
        displayCarrier = findViewById(R.id.network_operator);
        displayImage = findViewById(R.id.display_image);

        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if (telephonyManager != null) {
            carrierName = telephonyManager.getNetworkOperatorName();
        }

        if(carrierName != null) {
            displayCarrier.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.incoming_call, carrierName));
        }else {
            displayCarrier.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.incoming_call));
        }

        if(getFakeName().isEmpty()){
            displayName.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.unknown_name));
        }
        else {
            displayName.setText(getFakeName());
        }

        if(getFakeNumber().isEmpty()){
            displayNumber.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.unknown_number));
        }
        else {
            displayNumber.setText(getFakeNumber());
        }

        alarmOffButton = findViewById(R.id.hang_up_call);
        alarmOffButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReciever.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                stopService(intent);
                if (alarmManager != null) {
                    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private String getFakeName(){
        String contactName = null;
        Intent i = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = i.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            contactName = bundle.getString("USER_FAKE_NAME");
        }
        return contactName;
    }

    private String getFakeNumber(){
        String contactNumber = null;
        Intent i = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = i.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            contactNumber = bundle.getString("USER_FAKE_NUMBER");
        }
        return contactNumber;
    }
}
```

The code I am using in the `FakeRinger` activity is not working. The alarm is not stopping. Can anybody tell me where I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell why you are navigating back to **AlarmReciever** from **FakeRinger** activity?

**FakeRinger**:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReciever.class);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
```

Try using,

**FakeRinger**:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
 AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
 if (alarmManager != null) {
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It gives me this error
`Process: com.example.mani.fakecall, PID: 16049
                                                                           java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent {  }`

Comment: checkout my updated answer. Remove  stopService(intent) from your code

Comment: post the logcat